# How to update information for a variable depending on other variable in r?

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

`df_input` is the data frame I have and I want to transform it into `df_output`.

For instance, as the year 2001-2003 is assembly=1 and we have a winner in 2001. It means we have a winner as long as the assembly doesn't change.

```
    df_input <- data.frame(winner  = c(1,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0),
                           party = c("A",0,0,0,"B",0,0,0,"C",0,0,0,0), 
                           assembly= c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4), 
                           year = c(2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013))    
    
    df_output <- data.frame(winner  = c(1,1,1,0,2,2,0,0,1,1,0,0,0),
                            party = c("A","A","A",0,"B","B",0,0,"C","C",0,0,0),
                            assembly= c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4), 
                            year = c(2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013))
```

How can I update the same information as in the winner column depending on "assembly"?

EDIT: How to do it if there is an additional string variable, "party"? Look at the edit:

I get the following error after implementing this code:

```
    df_output <- df_input %>%
      mutate(df_input$party = if_else(is.na(df_input$party)==FALSE, df_input$party, NA_real_)) %>%
      group_by(assembly) %>%
      fill(df_input$party) %>%
      ungroup() %>%
      replace_na(list(df_input$party = 0))
```

Error:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"      ungroup() %>%
      replace_na(list(df_input$party ="
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to use `tidyr::fill` like so:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)   

df_input %>%
  mutate(winner = if_else(winner > 0, winner, NA_real_)) %>% 
  group_by(assembly) %>% 
  fill(winner) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  replace_na(list(winner = 0))
#> # A tibble: 13 × 3
#>    winner assembly  year
#>     <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1      1        1  2001
#>  2      1        1  2002
#>  3      1        1  2003
#>  4      0        2  2004
#>  5      2        2  2005
#>  6      2        2  2006
#>  7      0        3  2007
#>  8      0        3  2008
#>  9      1        3  2009
#> 10      1        3  2010
#> 11      0        4  2011
#> 12      0        4  2012
#> 13      0        4  2013
```

Comment: Thanks, Stefan. It is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Hello Stefan. How can we also integrate string variables? Look at the edited version of the question. I added new variable "party"

Comment: Hej @Fuser. Except one small change it's the same code. But first: Get rid of all the `df_input$` you added to the code. That#s not necessary. Second. Replace `mutate(winner = if_else(winner > 0, winner, NA_real_)) %>%` with `mutate(party = ifelse(party > 0, party, NA)) %>%`  and of course replace all other instances of `winner` with `party`too.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a base R way with `cumsum` and `ave`.
Note the use of the new lambda function `\(x)` introduced in R 4.1.0. If it gives an error, use the older `function(x)`.

```
with(df_input, ave(winner, assembly, FUN = \(x){
  y <- cumsum(x != 0) != 0
  if(any(y)) x[y] <- x[min(which(y))]
  x
}))
# [1] 1 1 1 0 2 2 0 0 1 1 0 0 0
```

Just assign the result back to column `winner`.

```
df_output <- df_input
df_output$winner <- with(df_output, ave(winner, assembly, FUN = \(x){
  y <- cumsum(x != 0) != 0
  if(any(y)) x[y] <- x[min(which(y))]
  x
}))
```

---

### Edit

Following [Henrik's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70236683/how-to-update-information-for-a-variable-depending-on-other-variable-in-r/70236819?noredirect=1#comment124159599_70236819), here is the much simpler `cummax` solution.

```
with(df_input, ave(winner, assembly, FUN = cummax))
```

Comment: Wouldn't `cummax` work? `with(df_input, ave(winner, assembly, FUN = cummax))`.

Comment: @Henrik Yes, it would. Thanks, I had completely forgotten `cummax`.

Answer (score 2):

**Update: See comments:**

```
library(dplyr)
df_input %>% 
  group_by(assembly) %>% 
  mutate(winner = case_when(first(winner) > 0 ~ first(winner),
                            lag(winner, default=0) > winner ~ lag(winner),
                            TRUE ~ winner))
```

```
   winner assembly  year
    <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
 1      1        1  2001
 2      1        1  2002
 3      1        1  2003
 4      0        2  2004
 5      2        2  2005
 6      2        2  2006
 7      0        3  2007
 8      0        3  2008
 9      1        3  2009
10      1        3  2010
11      0        4  2011
12      0        4  2012
13      0        4  2013
```

**First answer(not accounting for row 3)**
We can make use of `lag` function after grouping by `assembly`

```
library(dplyr)
df_input %>% 
  group_by(assembly) %>% 
  mutate(winner = ifelse(lag(winner, default = 0) > winner, lag(winner), winner))
```

```
Groups:   assembly [4]
   winner assembly  year
    <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
 1      1        1  2001
 2      1        1  2002
 3      0        1  2003
 4      0        2  2004
 5      2        2  2005
 6      2        2  2006
 7      0        3  2007
 8      0        3  2008
 9      1        3  2009
10      1        3  2010
11      0        4  2011
12      0        4  2012
13      0        4  2013
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, TarJae, one error is that the row #3 winner also needs to be 1. Thanks again

Comment: I was wondering how to get it done with `lag`, but failed since I didn‘t know how to reliably change the Na for the first value per group. BTW your group 1 result doesn‘t satisfy the output from the TO

Comment: Thank you. I missed. Please see my update.

Comment: Hello! How can we also integrate string variables? Look at the edited version of the question. I added a new variable "party":